# Fixing a variable in JuMP / Julia

Tags: optimization, julia, modeling, ampl, julia-jump

I have an AMPL code like this:

```
param N;
set R := 1..N;
set V := 1..N;
initializeSendPrepareReq{i in R, v in V}: SendPrepReq[1, i, v] = 0;
```

I need to write it in Julia using JuMP.

```
N = 10
R = 1:N
V = 1:N
?
```

I know I probably need to use JuMP.fix() but don't know how. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in R, v in V
   fix(SendPrepReq[1, i, v], 0)
end
```

If `SendPrepReq` has other bounds, you need

```
for i in R, v in V
   fix(SendPrepReq[1, i, v], 0; force = true)
end
```

Here is the relevant documentation: https://www.juliaopt.org/JuMP.jl/stable/variables/#JuMP.fix

Answer (score -1):

Just use zeros() fonction

```
N=10
SendPrepReq=zeros(1,N,N) or SendPrepReq=zeros(Int,1,N,N)
```

Or if you really want to use for loop:

```
N=10
R = 1:N
V = 1:N
for r in R
   for v in V 
      SendPrepReq[1,r,v]=0
   end
end
```

If SendPrepReq is a variable:

```
for r in R
   for v in V 
      @constraint(model, SendPrepReq[1,r,v] == 0 )
   end
end
```